# Flutter FCM push notification custom sound not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I need help because I don't know what's wrong with this. I'm trying to make push notification using FCM (firebase) and I did the docs step-by-step and still cannot use the sound that I wanted, Based on the docs I was supposed to save the sound (.mp3) file in res/raw android root of the project. I already did that and as for the payload it was like this

```
{
 "priority": "high",
 "to": "TOKEN_HERE,
 "notification": {
   "title": "NOTIFICATION TITLE",
   "body": "NOTIFICATION BODY",
   "sound":"notification.mp3"
 },
}
```

The notification appear but still has default ringtone to it, can someone tell me what's wrong with it, thank you.

Currently I have tried using audioplayer package to simulate the sound but it is not the right way, many of tutorial on YouTube did this and I already follow it step-by-step but still could not produce the custom sound from my payload

Comment: Please refer to this document for assistance: [link](https://medium.com/@farhanaslam910/how-to-play-custom-sound-fcm-notification-in-flutter-471016bf8760). I hope it proves helpful in resolving your issue.